# HTML element grows every time I rotate iPhone (or Safari window size crosses breakpoint)

Tags: ios, css, safari

I've reproduced an issue I've seen as a minimal (or close to it) example. You can see it here: http://nyh.name/walker.html

(In case of link rot, and so the source is easily viewable, the full HTML and CSS follows at the end of this post.)

If I view this page on my iPhone 6 in portrait (375 "pixels" width), and then rotate it to landscape (667 "pixels" width), the "foo" element suddenly gains a lot of top padding. If I use Safari's Remote Web Inspector, the "Box Model" view colors that area as though it *is* padding, though the padding values all show as "-".

What makes this *really* interesting is that if I rotate it back to portrait, it keeps (some of) that padding. If I keep rotating it back and forth, it just keeps growing.

I can reproduce this in Safari (8.0.3 on OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite) by opening the page and moving the window width back and forth across the breakpoint. You may need to open the Web Inspector docked to the right side to be able to get the viewport narrow enough:

[image: Animated screenshot]

Any ideas for how to fix, mitigate or work around this issue? (Assuming I want different font sizes and `display: table-cell`.)

Full HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Repro</title>
  <style>
    @media (min-width: 451px) {
      body {
        font-size: 100px;
      }
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: table;
    }

    .foo,
    .bar {
      display: table-cell;
    }

    .foo {
      background: blue;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .button {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="foo">
      foo
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="button">
        bar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found some web form and submitted this to Apple as a bug, though I doubt anything will come of it anytime soon.

Comment: Since this minimal example revealed that the problem only seems to happen if the font size changes on rotation, I worked around it by changing that breakpoint from 451 px to 737 px – that's larger than the largest side of the iPhone 6 Plus at 736 "px" and smaller than the smallest side of the iPad mini at 768 "px". So for all (I hope) mobile Apple devices, the font size in portrait and landscape will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font-size in the body tag to a lower value will solve it.

Comment: Yeah, I spent some time reducing this to a close-to-minimal example, so changing almost *anything* will make it go away :) But as long as the body font-size is larger than the `.foo` and `.button` size you'll see this issue – I just went with a huge value to make the issue more visible. You can see it with 16px vs. 14px, for example.